# Rabbitmq exchange fanout problems

Tags: tomcat, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

To communicate events in our cluster of tomcats we use rabbitmq and exchange fanout architecture. Every server is subscribed to exchange through temporary queue. Everything seems to work fine but time to time one or more consumers lose the connection and do not process message without leaving some useful information in logs a part of some broken pipe message.

Btw we use load balancer between rabbit cluster and our servers.

Any suggestion where could be the issue or what configuration should we review?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't auto acknowledge messages for start. In this way, if the consumer dies or whatever messages are re-queued. So, finish processing the message and then do explicit acknowledge.

Also with rabbit mq cluster, it's important to consider which queues you want mirrors etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. Avoid to use temporany queues, use persitent queues
2. Check the load/balancer configuration, if you have "connection closed" inside the logs, maybe it is the LB that close the connections after an Idle time.
3. Check your `heartbeart` configuration.

if you can, post the logs.